# How do I pass an extra variable to typeahead.js

Tags: php, jquery, typeahead.js

Im using typeahead.js to search live data from database but I don't know where is the problem?

I tried to pass a second variable inside typeahead function but it seems I failed making it work.
Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Here is the full code:

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control"  placeholder=" Search an item" autocomplete="off"> 
<select id="platform" >
  <option  value="0"  selected=""> Select a platform    </option>
  <option  value="1"  selected=""> Platform 1    </option>
  <option  value="2"  selected=""> Platform 2    </option>
  ... etc ..
</select>

<button class="btn btn-theme" type="submit" id="search-form">Search </button>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').typeahead({
    var platform=$("#platform").val();

    source: function(query,platform, result) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/live-search.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          query: query, platform: platform
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          result($.map(data, function(item) {
            return item;
          }));
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

AJAX:

```
<?php

require('../config/connect.php');
$platform= $_POST["platform"];
$request = $_POST["query"];
$sth = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE title LIKE ? AND platform=? LIMIT 25");
$sth->execute('%".$request."%', $platform);
$results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$data = array();

    if($sth->rowCount() != 0){
      foreach($results as $result):
           $data[] = $result->title;
      endforeach;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**The code below works just fine:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').typeahead({

    source: function(query, result) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/live-search.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          query: query
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          result($.map(data, function(item) {
            return item;
          }));
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

AJAX:

```
require('../config/connect.php');

$request = $_POST["query"];
$sth = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE title LIKE ? LIMIT 25");
$sth->execute('%".$request."%');
$results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$data = array();

    if($sth->rowCount() != 0){
      foreach($results as $result):
           $data[] = $result->title;
      endforeach;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```